# What is the difference between Serverless containers and App Engine flexible with custom runtimes?

Tags: containers, serverless, app-engine-flexible

I came across the article : [Bringing the best of serverless to you](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/07/bringing-the-best-of-serverless-to-you.html)
where I came to know about upcoming product called **Serverless containers on Cloud Functions** which is currently in Alpha.

As described in the article:

> Today, we’re also introducing serverless containers, which allow you
>   to run container-based workloads in a fully managed environment and
>   still only pay for what you use.

and in [GCP solutions page](https://cloud.google.com/serverless/)

> Serverless containers on Cloud Functions enables you to run your own containerized workloads on
>   GCP with all the benefits of serverless. And you will still pay only
>   for what you use. If you are interested in learning more about
>   serverless containers, please sign up for the alpha.

So my question is **how this serverless containers different from app engine flexible with custom runtime, which also use a docker file?**

And it's my suspicion, since mentioned named is **Serverless containers on Cloud Functions**, the differentiation may include role of cloud functions. If so what is the role played by cloud functions in the serverless containers?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is a Serverless Container?**

As stated on the [official blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/cloud-functions-serverless-platform-is-generally-available) (search for Serverless Containerss), it's basically a Cloud Function running inside a custom environment defined by the Dockerfile.

It is stated on the official blog post:

> With serverless containers, we are providing the same underlying
>   infrastructure that powers Cloud Functions, but you’ll be able to
>   simply provide a Docker image as input.

So, instead of deploying your code on the CF, you could also just deploy the Docker image with the runtime and the code to execute.

**What's the difference between this Cloud Functions with custom runtimes vs App Engine Flexible?**

There are 5 basic differences:

1. **Network**: On GAE Flexible you can customize the network the instances run. This let's you add firewalls rules to restrict egress and ingress traffic, block specific ports or specify the [SSL](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-managed-ssl-for-google-app-engine) you wish to run.
2. **Time-Out**: Cloud Functions can run for a maximum of [9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout), Flexible on the other hand, can run indefinitely.
3. **Ready only environment**: Cloud Functions environment is read-only while Flexible could be written *(this is only intended to store spontaneous information as once the Flexible instance is restarted or terminated, all the stored data is lost)*.
4. **Cold Boot**: Cloud Functions are fast to deploy and fast to start compared to Flexible. This is because Flexible runs inside a VM, thus this extra time is taken in order for the VM to start.
5. **How they work**: Cloud functions are event driven (ex: upload of photo to cloud storage executing a function) on the other hand flexible is request driven.(ex: handling a request coming from a browser)

As you can see, been able to deploy a small amount of code without having to take care of all the things listed above is a feature.

Also, take into account that Serverless Containers are still in Alpha, thus, many things could change in the future and there is still not a lot of documentation explaining in-depth it's behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I do not see any difference between app engine flex with docker file and serverless containers. what you are differentiating seems like CF vs AE flex. App engine is also serverless, google calls it serverless before it was cool. May be this serverless containers are rebranding of AE flex with improvements

Comment: Serverless Containers are not a rebranding of GAE Flexible, they are an extension of the Cloud Functions. It is stated on the official blog post: "With serverless containers, we are providing the same underlying infrastructure that powers Cloud Functions, but you’ll be able to simply provide a Docker image as input.". So, instead of deploying your code on the CF, you just deploy the Docker image with the runtime and the code to execute.

Comment: What is the underlying infrastructure of CF, is not it a VM pool?

Comment: Not exactly. As you see in this official video of Google Cloud Platform: https://youtu.be/LtELzpw1l1M?t=1584. They first describe Kubernetes as the building blocks of Knative. And then, they describe Serverless Containers on Cloud Functions running with Knative.

Comment: thanks for the resource, its better to explain the underlying infrastructure of cloud functions in the answer. then I will do some tweaks and accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, suggested a edit, since 5th point is not valid, since CF RAM, CPU could be customized.  I will accept answer then.

Answer (score 2):

#### What are Cloud Funtions?

From the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview#functions):

> Google Cloud Functions is a serverless execution environment for building and connecting cloud services. With Cloud Functions you write simple, single-purpose functions that are attached to events emitted from your cloud infrastructure and services. Your function is triggered when an event being watched is fired. Your code executes in a fully managed environment. There is no need to provision any infrastructure or worry about managing any servers.

In simple words, the Cloud Function is triggered by some event (HTTP request, PubSub message, Cloud Storage file insert...), runs the code of the function, returns a result and then the function dies.

Currently there are available [four runtime environments](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes):

- Node.js 6
- Node.js 8 (Beta)
- Python (Beta)
- Go (Beta)

With the **Serverless containers on Cloud Functions** product it is intended that you can provide your own custom runtime environment with a Docker Image. But the life cycle of the Cloud Function will be the same:

`It is triggered > Runs > Outputs Result > Dies`

#### App Engine Flex applications

Applications running in the [App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) are deployed to virtual machines, i.e Google Cloud Compute Engine instances. You can choose the type of machine you want use and the resources (CPU, RAM, disk space). The App Engine flexible environment automatically scales your app up and down while balancing the load.

As well as in the case of the Cloud Functions there runtimes provided by Google but if you would like to use an alternative implementation of Python, Java, Node.js, Go, Ruby, PHP, .NET you can use [Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes). Or even you can work with another language like C++, Dart..., you just need to provide a Docker Image for your Application.

#### What are differences between Cloud Functions and App Engine Flex apps?

The main difference between them are its life cycle and the use case.

As commented above a Cloud Function has a defined life cycle and it dies when it task concludes. They should be used to do 1 thing and do it well.

On the other hand an Application running on the GAE Flex environment will always have at least 1 instance running. The typical case for this applications are to serve several endpoints where users can do REST API calls. But they provide more flexibility as you have full control over the Docker Image provided. You can do "almost" whatever you want there.

Comment: thanks for the effort. but this does not answer my question, most of the information I already know.